# How to override a method of another class instance in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, overriding

I have a class with a Fragment instance in it and want to override the fragment methods. How can I make this kind of overriding here?

```
class MyClass(val fragment: Fragment) {
    init {
        fragment.onActivityCreated = onActivityCreated //what should be written?
    }

    fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        actions()
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not possible, don't you have access to the Fragment you wanted to target?

Comment: I pass a `fragment` parameter but I want to separate the code and override the method in `MyClass`.

Comment: I think you need to override methods in another class then pass that class instead of Fragment class

Comment: Probably, you should create a class extending the Fragment and accept that as a parameter, and it has some method to set what to fire up when onActivityCreated is called, possibly by a lambda `(Bundle?) -> Unit`. Though this design is bad, you should really use OOP concepts and build different fragments for different purpose instead.

Comment: Currently I override `onActivityCreated` in a main fragment and run myClass.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState) there. But I'd like to make MyClass more independent.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu could you provide an example? I think this wrapper can be not  general-purposed because I need to override other methods in other wrappers like `MyClass2`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a deleted answer, the completed mechanism looks like this:

```
class MyClass<T>(private val viewModelPayments: PaymentsViewModel, val fragment: T) where T : Fragment, T : Featured {

    init {
        fragment.doOnActivityCreated(::onActivityCreated)
        fragment.doOnActivityResult(::onActivityResult)
    }

    private fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //...
    }

    private fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) { 
        //...
    }
}

interface Featured {
    fun doOnActivityCreated(action: (savedInstanceState: Bundle?) -> Unit)
    fun doOnActivityResult(action: (requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) -> Unit)
}

abstract class FeatureFragment : BaseFragment(), Featured {
    private var onActivityCreatedAction: ((savedInstanceState: Bundle?) -> Unit)? = null
    private var onActivityResultAction: ((requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun doOnActivityCreated(action: (savedInstanceState: Bundle?) -> Unit) {
        onActivityCreatedAction = action
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        onActivityCreatedAction?.invoke(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun doOnActivityResult(action: (requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) -> Unit) {
        onActivityResultAction = action
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        onActivityResultAction?.invoke(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```